# vim -q not taking result from grep in bash

Tags: bash, search, vim, grep, zsh

i am very new to bash programing and trying to add the result from `grep` to `vim -q` so that i can [open the result in vim](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100032/given-the-result-of-grep-n-how-can-i-open-vim-in-that-specific-line-using-on)
but vim throwing errors

```bash
# search and add result to vim quickfix
fury(){
   local pat=$1
   local l="${2:-.}"
   local result=$(grep -n "$pat" $l)
   if [ -z "$result" ]
   then
        echo "no result found"
   else
        vim -q <($result) +:copen
    fi
}
```

[image: errors]

Comment: `vim -q <(echo "$result") +:copen`

Answer (score 3):

It is not Vim that is throwing errors, it is your shell. And for good reasons.

First, that `<()` thing is called ["Process Substitution"](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html). It executes a command and exposes its output as a "file" (actually a "file descriptor"). In the example below, `diff` actually sees two files, each containing the output of the command in the parentheses:

```
# what you type
$ diff <(ls /tmp/foo) <(ls /tmp/bar)

# what really happens
$ diff /dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/64
```

or, with Vim and `grep`:

```
# what you type
$ vim <(grep -n foo /here)

# what really happens
$ vim -q /dev/fd/65
```

Second, `$ vim -q` expects a file *or something that looks like a file*. The linked solution works because Vim gets a file. You are storing the output of `grep` in a variable and using that variable between the parentheses. That output is just "text", therefore:

- it is not a command,
- and Vim's `-q` expects a file anyway.

You can either use an actual command:

```
$ vim -q <(echo "$result")
```

or write the output of `grep` in a temporary file:

```
$ vim -q /tmp/foo/dosydtosdyu
```

Comment: ah got it thanks for the explaination @romainl

just curious if we already have output stored in a variable
i dont think i need substitution 

is there any other way we can accomplish this ?

Comment: @MAK, I have edited my answer for clarity.

Comment: The output of `ls -l <(:)` should also show some info.